# How can i detect the Link button fire command-button in gridview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Strange issue that is i have develop a web application in one of the form i am using Gridview control with command button to view the row data.If in Gridview data have only record then link button working fine if it is more than one record not working link buttons i can't under stand, this is very strange issue to me i have use !Page.IsPostBack also in pageload event,please help me .....

```
     protected void grdmanageloans_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.CommandName == "Info") 
        {
            try
        {
            int loanid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            Session["Loanid"] = loanid;
            Session["Edit"] = "Edit";
            TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 1;
            Session["TabContainer1"] ="loantab";
            Session["Tabloan"] = "Tabloan";
            Response.Redirect("Mortgageclient.aspx");

        }
        catch { }
                    }
       if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            try
            {

                int LoanId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                var PmtScheduleHistory = from del in mortgageentity.Pmt_Schedule_History where del.Loan.Loan_ID == LoanId select del;
                var LoanPayment = from del in mortgageentity.Payments where del.Loan_ID == LoanId select del;

                if (PmtScheduleHistory.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var DelPmtScheduleHistory = (from del in mortgageentity.Pmt_Schedule_History where del.Loan.Loan_ID == LoanId select del).First();
                    mortgageentity.DeleteObject(DelPmtScheduleHistory);
                    mortgageentity.SaveChanges();
                }
                var Getpayments = from db in mortgageentity.Payments where db.Loan_ID == LoanId select db;
                if (Getpayments.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var i in Getpayments)
                    {
                        mortgageentity.DeleteObject(i);
                        mortgageentity.SaveChanges();
                    }
                } 

                if (LoanPayment.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var DelPmtScheduleHistory = (from del in mortgageentity.Payments where del.Loan_ID == LoanId select del.Payment_Status.PaymentStatus_ID).First();
                    mortgageentity.DeleteObject(DelPmtScheduleHistory);
                    mortgageentity.SaveChanges();
                }

                var deletedata = (from del in mortgageentity.Loans where del.Loan_ID == LoanId select del).First();
                mortgageentity.DeleteObject(deletedata);
                mortgageentity.SaveChanges();
                BindData();
            }
            catch { }
        }

        if (e.CommandName == "AddNewloan")
        {
            Session["Addnewloan"] = "Addloan";
            Response.Redirect("Information.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Here is my .aspx page

```
     <asp:GridView ID="grdmanageloans" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
                                                            GridLines="Both" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" OnRowCommand="grdmanageloans_RowCommand"
                                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdmanageloans_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowFooter="true"
                                                            OnPageIndexChanging="grdmanageloans_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="grdmanageloans_Rowdatabound">
                                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F3F9FB" />
                                                            <RowStyle BackColor="#FEFEFE" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#F3F9FB" />
                                                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F3F9FB" />
                                                            <RowStyle Wrap="False" />
                                                            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#1F476F" />
                                                            <Columns>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LoanID" Visible="true">
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblloanid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Loan_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Loan Number">
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblLoanNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LoanNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Month Pay Amt" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMonthPayAmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Getammount(Eval("MonthPayAmt","{0:F2}")) %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblpropaddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PropAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblpropcity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PropCity") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblpropstate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PropState") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ClientID" Visible="false">
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblclientid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Client_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>


                                                                      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkeinfo" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Info"
                                                                            CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Loan_ID")%>'>Information</asp:LinkButton>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                               </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            </Columns>
                                                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Only your code can tell the tale, please post

Comment: Please elaborate your question or post code

Comment: Post the code dude. Most probably you're binding the event's wrong..

Comment: Hi dudes thank for all giving response ,It has 1736 lines code here.

Comment: can you just put a break point and check whether it is coming in **grdmanageloans_RowCommand**

Comment: Where you assigning command arguments of link button?

Comment: you should post the code of the event that is executed OnItemBound or sth. like it. because there you should be binding events to your commands.

Comment: I have use the break point to check whether it is coming or not but it is coming when the record is only one.If ther is more than 1 record it is not fire break poin to debug.

Comment: Ok dudes now it is working fine thank you to all .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkeinfo" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Info"
                                                                            CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Loan_ID") %>'>Information</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a RESTful architecture to not save those parameters in Session and make pages kind'ev tightly coupled? Just create links named **Info** in your Grid instead of buttons (which post back data) with those parameters appended to the end of them as **querystring**. This is nicer approach and the result is the same.

Comment: but if data is confidential then the use of session is better

Comment: Yeah, if that's your reason, it's totally logical to use Session.